# How to build custom OTP screen like given image in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, screen

I'm trying to build OTP Screen like below image but not able to built exact in image.
appLogo should be in the TopCenter and Submit button should be in the BottomCenter , OTP elements should be in  the center of the screen and OtpBox should be like in image with 1 limit character.

[image]

I tried to build like it but not able to built:

Here My screen which i have built:
[image]

MY CODE:

```
return Scaffold(
     body:  Center(
       child: SingleChildScrollView(
         child: Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
           child: Column(
             children: <Widget>[
               Container(
                 height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/4.5,
                 width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2.5,
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   image: DecorationImage(
                     image: AssetImage('assets/TriggerTrackerIcons/splash_logo@3x.png'),
                   )
                 ),
               ),
               SizedBox(height: 50,),
               Container(
                 alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                 child: Text("Enter OTP:", style:TextStyle(fontWeight:FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20, color: Colors.orange))
               ),
               SizedBox(height: 8,),
               Row(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                 children: <Widget>[
                  otpBoxBuilder(),
                  SizedBox(width: 5,),
                  otpBoxBuilder(),
                  SizedBox(width: 5,),
                   otpBoxBuilder(),
                  SizedBox(width: 5,),
                   otpBoxBuilder(),
                 ],
               ),
               SizedBox(height: 50,),
               InkWell(
                 child: Container(
                   alignment: Alignment.center,
                   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/15,
                   color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                   child: Text("Submit", style:TextStyle(fontWeight:FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white)),
                 ),
                 onTap: (){
                   Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>HomePage()));
                 },
               ),
             ],
           ),
         ),
       ),
     ),
   );
```

OTP BOX BUILDER:

```
Widget otpBoxBuilder(){
   return Container(
     alignment: Alignment.center,
     height: 70,
     width: 70,
     child: TextField(
       keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
       maxLength: 1,
       decoration: InputDecoration(
         border: InputBorder.none
       ),
     ),
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
       border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)
     ),
   );
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made it right but need some tweaks and modifications to achieve the expected UI,

Don't wrap everything inside the `SingleChildScrollView`. It will make the entire screen scrollable.

Use `Expanded` along with `Column` and `Container` to achieve what you need. Refer the below code snippet.

```
  Widget _body(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: _topLayout(context),
        ),
        _bottomButton(context)
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _boxWithLable(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 25),
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Text("Boxes:",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Colors.orange))),
        _boxBuilder()
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _boxBuilder() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        _box(),
        _box(),
        _box(),
        _box(),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _box() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 3),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      height: 50,
      width: 50,
      child: TextField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        maxLength: 1,
        decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none, counterText: ''),
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)),
    );
  }

  Widget _headerImage() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
      child: Image.asset(
        "assets/someimage.png",
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        height: 160,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _bottomButton(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print('clicked');
            },
            child: Text('Submit'),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _topLayout(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[_headerImage(), _boxWithLable(context)],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Now call the `_body` inside your build method

```
Scaffold(
        appBar: 'OTP',
        body: _body(context),
      )
```

Try and let me know if it is working for you.

Comment: How about forward and backward focus? I think it's missing from the solution.

Comment: @ParthDave OP is about UI alignment and as you asked about focus, you can use Focusnode in Flutter to customize focus as you wanted !!

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan thank you so much sir , I implemented your code & displaying perfectly for submitButton but my header image widget is still in center not on topCenter but I changed a little bit & working perfectly.

Comment: Glad it worked. I didn't give you the exact answer but a way to achieve what you need. Your modification to my answer is the key. @ShrutiRamnandanSharma Kudos..!!

Answer (score 2):

I modified tour boxBuilderCode a little !
and Enter OTP container margin left to 25,
Note: I dont have that brain image !

```
Widget otpBoxBuilder() {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      height: 70,
      width: 70,
      child: TextField(
        style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 23, color: Colors.blue),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        maxLength: 1,
        decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none, counterText: ''),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
      decoration:
          BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 3)),
    );
  }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

@Ragu Swaminathan I just modified your code for little bit:

[image]

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:  Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
        child: _body(context),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _body(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        _headerImage(),
        Expanded(
          child: _boxWithLable(context),
        ),
        _bottomButton(context)
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _boxWithLable(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Text("Enter OTP:",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 20,
              color: Colors.orange
            )
          )
        ),
        _boxBuilder()
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _boxBuilder() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        _box(),
        _box(),
        _box(),
        _box(),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _box() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 3),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      height:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/14,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/8,
      child: TextField(
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        maxLength: 1,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none, 
          counterText: '',
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(20)
        ),
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue,width: 2)),
    );
  }

  Widget _headerImage() {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:25),
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
      child: Image.asset(
        "assets/TriggerTrackerIcons/splash_logo@3x.png",
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        height: 160,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _bottomButton(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          InkWell(
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/15,
              color: Colors.orangeAccent,
              child: Text("Submit", style:TextStyle(fontWeight:FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white)),
            ),
            onTap: (){
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>HomePage()));
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 50,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```